# Kafka - what are differences in confluent distributions

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am going through the documentation confluent kafka distributions and come across the following distribution types . What are the fundamental differences between each

1. Download Community Features
2. Download free
3. Download Enterprise Tarball
4. Download Community Tarball
5. Download Open Source Tarball

https://www.confluent.io/previous-versions

https://www.confluent.io/download

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two distributions of Confluent Platform: Community, and Commercial (Enterprise). You can see a chart of the differences between the two here: https://www.confluent.io/download/#confluent-platform

Earlier versions of Confluent Platform were licensed differently, which is why you see reference to `open source` tarball instead of `Community` tarball in 5.1 and later when it was [relicensed](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/).

Tarball is one of the available distribution methods, along with zip, rpm, deb, Docker, and so on.

Comment: I got, but if it is just two versions - why there are so many flavors like 5 i had listed there - for eg what is the different between "free" and "community features" ( Both sounded free )

Comment: Where did you get that list of five from?

Comment: I collected from the images (attached) . Hope, they had standard meaning

Comment: Great, Can you also please add some details about the differences between "free" and "community features" ( Both sounded free )